# VMware: OS choice on VM creation:

Tags: vmware-esx, operating-system

I'm using the vSphere client. When I create a new Virtual Machine I have a selection drop-down to choose the OS version. Except 32bit and 64bit version which I understand (because it's hardware related), I am wondering what difference does it make for VMware if I choose a specific version rather than another.

Example:

What difference does VMware if I choose RedHat 5 or RedHat 6? Does hardware look different? Is it just for information purpose? Why vmWare even has to know what operating system the guests are running on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VMWare chooses sane defaults for what abstracted hardware it presents to the OS.

It chooses those hardware abstractions that have good drivers available in the OS you selected.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.